How can I create MediaStream or MediaTrack from a downloaded mp3 audio?
I need to download an mp3 file from a server and pass audiostream to webrtc peer.
To do that I was trying to create MediaStream, but I have failed.
I have got an error in this line:
let newStream = newAudio.captureStream(); // ERROR here:
// TypeError: newAudio.captureStream is not a function

My code is as followed.
How can I get mediastream or track from an audio blob ?
function getFileFromServer(httpAddress) {
    let resp = fetch(httpAddress).then(getFile_Fulfilled, blob_Rejected);
    return;

} // function getFileFromServer(httpAddress)

function getFile_Fulfilled(response) {


    if (response.ok) {

        let fileBlob = response.blob();
        fileBlob.then(
            function blob_Fulfilled(f_blob) {

                // OK here

                let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(f_blob);

                // OK here

                try {
                    let newAudio = new Audio(blobURL);
                    newAudio.autoplay = false;
                    // newAudio.play();

                    console.log("--- newAudio ---");
                    console.log(newAudio);

                // Audio created - OK

                    let newStream = newAudio.captureStream(); // ERROR here:
                    // TypeError: newAudio.captureStream is not a function

                }
                catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            } // function blob_Fulfilled()
            ,
            function blob_Rejected(e) {

                console.log(e);

            } // function blob_Rejected()
        ); //let fileBlob =
    }
}


... Is it impossible to do ?

Thanks to all - the problem is solved:
ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
stream_dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(newAudio);
source.connect(stream_dest);

stream = stream_dest.stream;

